# Programmatically modification of CarouselView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have a CarouselView inside a ScrollView. To control the height I calculate it and modify it programmatically. It almost works, but the problem however is that it only works when the height is increased not when the height is decreased.

**CarouselView**

````
<CarouselView x:Name="cv" HeightRequest="8"  ItemsSource="{Binding Challenge.ChallengeParts}" VerticalOptions="Center" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChallengePartTemplate}" Position="{Binding PageCarouselPosition}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></CarouselView>```
````

**DataTemplate**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChallengePartTemplate">
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LimeGreen" VerticalOptions="Center">
      <Grid x:Name="rulesGrid">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <StackLayout x:Name="toggleShowRules" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
              <Label x:Name="showRulesText" Text="Vis regler fra video" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
          <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=BindingContext.ToggleShowRulesTappedCommand}" />
          </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
          </StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=BindingContext.ShowRules,Converter={StaticResource CaretConverter}}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
      </Grid>
      <StackLayout x:Name="showRulesStack" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=BindingContext.ShowRules}">
          <Grid Margin="20, 0, 0, 0">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <!--Antal spillere-->
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                  <Label Text="&#xf183;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
                  <Label Text="&#xf182;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout x:Name="numPlayersText" Spacing="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                  <Label Text="Antal spillere:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Micro" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding NumPlayers}" FontSize="Micro" />
              </StackLayout>
              <!--Nødvendigt udstyr-->
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                  <Label Text="&#xf45d;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Spacing="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                  <Label Text="Nødvendigt udstyr:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Micro" />
                  <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding NeededAccesories}" Spacing="0">
                      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                              <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="Micro" />
                          </DataTemplate>
                      </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                  </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
              <!--Regler-->
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                  <Label Text="&#xf46d;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                  <Label Text="Regler:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Micro" />
                  <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Rules}" Spacing="0">
                      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                              <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="Micro" />
                          </DataTemplate>
                      </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                  </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
          </Grid>
      </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Code behind**

```
var cvVisibleViews = cv.VisibleViews;
if(cvVisibleViews.Count > 0)
{
    var rulesStack = cvVisibleViews[0].FindByName<StackLayout>("showRulesStack");
    var toggleShowRules = cvVisibleViews[0].FindByName<StackLayout>("toggleShowRules");
    var showRulesText = cvVisibleViews[0].FindByName<Label>("showRulesText");

    double height = 0;
    height = height + toggleShowRules.Height;
    height = height + showRulesText.Height;
    if (rulesStack.IsVisible && rulesStack.Height > -1)
    {
        height = height + rulesStack.Height;
    }
    
    cv.HeightRequest = height;
}
```

It seems like the new height of the CarouselView is measured from the center of it. Like the content is placed outside above the CarouselView

[image: CV]
Any idea to realign the content inside the resized CarouselView?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try [expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander)?

Comment: You may look at Dynamic resizing of items.

Comment: Thank you. It is a nice component, but I dont really see how it should help me in this case? The problem is not, that the IsVisible does not work. The problem is that the CarouselView-height is not adjusted from the top. Using the Expander gives me the exact same result unfortunately.

Comment: @HongxinSui, thank you. I have tried to look at that, but I also dont see how that is helping in this case. Can you point to what part of my code I should be able to use ForceUpdateCode()? As far as I see it is not part of the CarouselView.

Comment: I want to provide you with this website:“https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/layout#dynamic-resizing-of-items”. And I hope I can help you.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't think that's the problem. The problem is, that when the CarouselView is in a ScrollView it will by default have the screen height. No matter the height of the content in it.